# Job is running even if there are no change to the files that are specified in rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Here is my GitLab job, it has rules specified to run the only when changes made to certain files. But, sometime job runs when MR is raised when though there are no changes to the files specified in rules, this happens to only certain MR's(one in 30-50 or so).

```
  stage: my-job
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:8009
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"
  services:
    - name: myorg.com/docker:dind
      alias: docker
  tags:
    - kind
  script:
    - sh ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/src/main/myScript1.sh
  except:
    refs:
      - schedule
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    changes:
      - src/main/myScript1.sh
      - src/main/Dockerfile
      - src/main/myScript2.sh
```

Git log for the files specified in above rules are also verified and they are untouched during the MR's which made the job to run.

Any issues with the rules/logic added to the job? Could someone please suggest/help?

Comment: Can you provide more information on when a pipeline is triggered and when it's not? Are they existing or new branches? Is it on initial creating of MR or subsequent commits after an MR is open?

Comment: @Arty-chan As said, the job is getting triggered only for once in 30-50 MR's. New branch.

Comment: Yes, but how do they compare? What pattern can you see with the ones that are being triggered? Once again, is the triggered job always on creation of MR or on subsequent commits?